# Ajax-like appearing/disappearing elements in Access 2010 web database project

Tags: user-interface, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to have a feature to allow users choose two different methods of cost calculation: either they can enter a yearly cost breakdown on a datasheet (2010: $10,000, 2011: $12,000, etc) or they can enter a flat yearly cost multiplied by the number of years they select.

If I were developing another kind of web application, I'd have radio buttons to select two different options. One option would display the datasheet, and the other option would display two text fields to enter values into. However, I understand that you can't have radio buttons in Access 2010 web databases. Also, is it possible to make elements appear and disappear based on a combo box selection?

If not, perhaps I could have two different combo box options: "enter yearly cost breakdown"
 or "enter flat yearly cost," which open the correct respective forms as pop-ups.

So, 1) can I have Ajax-like appearing and disappearing elements as triggered by a combo box (or ideally, radio buttons), and 2) if not, can anyone think of another clever way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you get a nice effect by using a tab control. You can place controls and even a sub form on that tab control.

So, you build a screen like this:

[image]

Then, simple set the visible property of the second tab = No. This will hide the tab (don't change this until you built the page since it will hide it! (use property sheet to hide/un-hide during development).

Now,  add some code to the after update event of the list box. Like this:

[image]

In the above, I have named the tabs PYear and PFlat.

The result is this (this is a animated gif I inserted):

[image]

Of course, you really probably could just dump the whole "list box" selection, and use a screen like this with the tabs (tabs are good UI, and users tend to grasp them quick):

[image]

So, you can hide a "set" of controls, and it really far less work and hassle then writing a bunch of JaveScript anyway. As noted, the "set" of controls you drop into each of the tabs can be sub forms, and also that of continues forms. So, the "hiding" as a set does work well in this case. I did have some format issues and found that I had to "start out" with the 2nd tab dispaled first (the first one being hidden). As noted, the listbox selecting is nice, but one could likly just go with using tabs in the first place.